# Usage of 'there' and 'an'

Tags: grammar

I don't know the exact difference between these two expressions:

> There is an apple on the table

and

> An apple is on the table

Can anyone explain the usage?

Answer (score 1):

These sentences differ in primary focus.
In the sentence **"An apple is on the table"** we are talking primarily about the apple (and where is it).
In the sentence **"There is an apple on the table"** we describe what is on the table (and it's an apple).

Comment: Appreciate your help so much! Are both these two expressions right in syntax？ Do both of them  sound natural?

Comment: @88881111, Yes, you can use any of these phrases, choosing the most appropriate one depending on the context.

Comment: So lovely you are!  You helps a lot. Really thank you !